# Bernoulli differential equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am considering the following elementary differential equation:
$$y'(x) = c y^2(x), \quad y(0)=x_0>0$$
for some given constant $c>0$. I consider this equation just for $x>0$, i.e. in the positive line.

This equation can be solved and the solution is given by
$$y(x) = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x_0}-cx}, \quad x\in \mathbb{R}_+.$$

The intuition is that since $y'(x)$ is positive then $y$ must be increasing which it is... But I don't understand why it explodes at $x=\frac{1}{cx_0}$. What is the intuition behind? Why can't $y$ just be increasing and well-defined for all values $x>0$? and there is a single point singularity? I really can't see the intuition behind.

Any idea help comment on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the function grows, so does the derivative. And the derivative grows at least constantly ($y^2 c \ge x_0^2 c$), so eventually $y$ will be larger than one. The function growth will be proportionate to the square of the function itself, and the square is larger than $y$ if $y > 1$. So as the function grows, the growth grows, and the function grows even faster, and this creates a vicious cycle culminating in the explosion.

EDIT: An intuition behind the point $z := 1/(x_0 c)$ is: The larger $x_0$ is, the quicker the process described above comes about, and the larger $c$ is, the quicker the process described above comes about.

For larger values than $z$ the function $y$ is negative. If it grows, $y^2$ shrinks. Thus, the growth of $y$ comes to a halt as soon as $y$ approaches the $x$-axis from below.

Comment: I see but then it goes well again for larger values even very big values of $x>>0$, it only explodes once.. and why at precisely $1/(cx_0)$.. I don't see the intuition of this point.

Comment: For larger values the function is negative. If it grows, $y^2$ shrinks. But on the precise point issue I've got to think a bit more.